# Target "${task}" does not exist in the project "build" for ant

Tags: java, ant, build

I am completely new to ant. I am using the following line to generate a war file (which contains compiled class files and a property file

```
 wrapperwar_jartask=${output_dir}/XYZWrapper.war,${wrapper_home},**
```

I'm getting the following error while running build

```
Target "${task}" does not exist in the project "build" for ant
```

I have no idea what the error means.Someone please help me to resolve this.

Comment: can you share your ant file

Comment: My ant.properties file looks like the one below.. Please look into it and provide your valuable suggestions...
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1vpxVHohpf93bkHVNxF_5NT5pMrc0CILGeedRB3Svx7M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: and the build.xml ?